# How to sort a store according to another store in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I have two store and i want to sort one store according other store.

Store1 store a model:

```
fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }
   ]
```

Store2 store model:

```
fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'subject',
            type: 'string'
        }
  ]
```

I sort the store2 by subject and i want to sort store1 according store2's id.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen sort event on the first store and accordingly sort the second store. Please take a look at the following fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/np5